# Deploying React Router application to Subfolder on Server

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

**The Problem**:

We have our website `https://website.com` and we are trying to deploy a react router application to `https://website.com/react-app`. Routing works fine if the user first navigates to `https://website.com/react-app` and then navigates around the app from there. However, if someone navigates to `https://website.com/react-app/home` directly (or via bookmark) they get a 404 even though `/home` is one of our routes.

**What We tried**:

In our package.json we have the `"homepage": "/react-app/"` set. Using BrowserRouter we set the `basename` prop to `/react-app` and the app works when deployed except for 404 when navigating directly to a nested route. We have heard that HashRouter can be useful in this situation, however, when we use HashRouter we are getting `https://website.com/react-app#/` instead of `https://website.com/react-app/#/`.

How can we configure this to allow users to navigate directly to nested routes in our React Router application deployed to a the `/react-app` Subfolder on our server?

React: 17.0.2, React-Router-Dom: 5.2.0

Comment: you need a rewrite rule on the server you are hosting the app (e.g. nginx, apache, etc ...)

Comment: [This article](https://blog.devgenius.io/deploying-your-react-app-to-hostgator-quick-and-painless-9807cf939532) was pretty helpful when I was trying to accomplish something similar

Comment: Is this work for you @BryceBy ?

If yes, Can you please share the configuration here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem must be not connected with React. Your React app is configured right. Check the configuration of your web server. Your webserver must return index.html with React application when the user navigates to any page.